# Rails App without DB: Easiest way to provide a small editable text (displayed as news on homepage)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a very small Rails app for a client that serves nearly only static content. It has no database in the background.

My client now needs a way to provide a small text which is shown on the home page. In it he wants to state the current deliver deadline of his product (which varies a lot). The easiest thing would be a small page where he could change the text in a textarea, protected by a password.

I wonder whether there is a very easy way for offering something like that without attaching a full DB to the app?

Comment: Do you need to persist that editable info? Do you need others to see your edit?

Comment: You can use a simple SQLite3 database, it is very easy to use, does not need any external installation (like PostgreSQL or MySQL services) and all the content is held in a single file (which can be committed in your VCS)

Comment: probably this link can help you https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/non-activerecord-models-in-rails-4--cms-25452

Answer (score 0):

The SQLite3 DB is the simplest, it just saves as a file in the `db/` directory (next to `schema.rb` etc.) and so doesn't require anything else be setup to use. This is the default you get for new Rails apps so may even already be present for you, if not `database.yml` just needs to use the `sqlite3` adapter and `database` is a file path, e.g.:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

If even that is too much, nothing stops you using plain files for simple things, either plain text, or JSON, or whatever.

e.g. [`str = IO.read file_name`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/IO.html#method-c-read) and [`IO.write file_name, str`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/IO.html#method-c-write). And for JSON you can use the stdlib [`JSON`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html) module.